# How do I send an image attachment via an Email form with Nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, attachment, nodemailer

I am new to coding backend stuff. What I am trying to do is have a customer fill out an email form, upload an attachment with a preview and send said image as an attachment to my email so I can set up the image to use for the site. Everything is being setup in React and Node.js. I can send the email form; I can even send an attachment with the email. The problem is the attachment is empty. I try to open the attachment in a new tab and it hangs and does nothing. If I try to download the attachment, it hangs and then says server error.

I have been scouring the internet, trying so many various things for days trying to get this thing to work. Watching tutorials, looking at other questions and suggestions, going through blog posts and nothing seems to work. I know there is a way to do this, but I have no idea what. I haven't found anything that works. Can please someone enlighten me on what I am doing wrong and how to actually get an image attachment to send? I have left my code here so people can review it. Thank you.

FRONT END

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      message: "",
      file: null,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleFileChange = this.handleFileChange.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const [file] = e.target.files;
    if (file) {
      this.setState({
        file: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
      });
      console.log(file);
    }
  };

  handleReset = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: "",
      [e.target.email]: "",
      [e.target.message]: "",
      [e.target.file]: null,
    });
  };

  async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { name, email, message, file } = this.state;

    const form = await axios.post("/api/form", {
      name,
      email,
      message,
      file,
    });

    if (file) {
      this.setState({
        file: URL.revokeObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        style={{ width: "200px", padding: "20px" }}
      >
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <label htmlFor="message">Message:</label>
        <input type="textarea" name="message" onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <label htmlFor="file">File:</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          name="file"
          accept="image/jpeg, jpg"
          onChange={this.handleFileChange}
          multiple={false}
        />

        <img src={this.state.file} alt="img" />

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

BACKEND

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require("fs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

app.post("/api/form", (req, res) => {
  nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    const htmlEmail = `
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Name: ${req.body.name}
        </li>
        <li>
          Email: ${req.body.email}
        </li>     
      </ul>
      <h3>Message</h3>
      <p>${req.body.message}</p>
    `;

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "********",
      port: ***,
      auth: {
        user: "********",
        pass: "********",
      },
    });

    let mailOptions = {
      from: "test@test.com",
      to: "testReceive@test.com",
      replyTo: "test@test.com",
      subject: "Test Message",
      text: req.body.message,
      html: htmlEmail,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: "AdvertImage.jpg",
          content: req.body.file,
          contentType: "image/jpg",
        },
      ],
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }

      console.log("Message sent: %s", info.message);
      console.log("Message URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    });
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you are missing something that processes multipart form data. Is `req.body.file` populated?

Comment: @Matt: Yes there is something populated in that object. I know because I get a name of the object if I add `req.body.file` to the contact details and send the email. I just don't get an image.

Comment: Yeah, so I think you need something that handles the multipart upload to get the image data (like [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload)). bodyParser is just doing the basic form stuff

Comment: Oh ok. I will see what I can do with it and let you know if I can get it working. Thank you :3

Comment: Ok so after messing around with this for more hours, I still can't get this to work and I don't really know what I am supposed to do. I tried busboy and formData and router and other things and I just cannot get this to work. With the current changes to my code, now I jsut get undefined in my fields. Can anyone tell me how am I supposed to get an image attachment emailed? I do not understand how to implement the code correctly to get it to work. Thank you.